# How to unbind properties by using razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I use razor pages.
I have this property

```
[BindProperty]
public ProductDto CreateProduct { get; set; }
```

In `OnPost` Method, I check `ModelState.IsValid` and everything is ok.
But when I send a request to my handlers that are next to my `OnPost` method the validation will be false.
The reason is `ModelState` check my handler inputs and also `CreateProduct` that used bind property attribute, how can I unbind property that use `BindProperty` attribute when I send request to the hanlders.

```
public IActionResult OnPostAddBrand(AddBrandDto model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // AddBrandDto is valid but I got here.
        Return Json(false);
    }
    // todo: SaveBrand
    Return Json(true);
}
```

I know if I don't use `BindProperty` attribute and get the object from the method inputs, problem will be solved, like this:

```
public ProductDto CreateProduct { get; set; }
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(ProductDto createProduct)
{
}
```

But is there any other way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ModelState.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary.remove) to remove properties from the `ModelStateDictionary` e.g.

```
ModelState.Remove("Password");
```

If you want to "unbind" a complex property, you can use reflection to remove its properties:

```
foreach(var prop in ProductDto.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    ModelState.Remove($"{nameof(ProductDto)}.{prop.Name}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes your answer is correct but I have a question about razor pages, I use razor pages for a while but razor sometimes create a problem that I have never those in MVC, for example I can't use PageRemote attribute in HttpPost method, I can't set route for my handlers with attribute. Is these problem occurred because It's new than MVC and needs time for fix it ?

Comment: @JackLee PageRemote works in Razor Pages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation/remote-validation. If you are having problems implementing it, you should post another question.